# Get Multiple Data from Powershell in PHP

Tags: php, powershell

Right now I have a very basic code which takes form data from HTML

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
// Get the variables submitted by POST in order to pass them to the 
//PowerShell script:
$servername = $_POST["servername"];

// Path to the PowerShell script. Remember double backslashes:
$psScriptPath = "C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\Scripts\\Inventory.ps1";

// Execute the PowerShell script, passing the parameters: 
$query = passthru("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File $psScriptPath $servername 2>&1");
echo $query;

// Else the user hit submit without all required fields being filled out:
?>
```

The thing is the Inventory Script Currently takes data and put it into HTML. So Is there a way in PHP that it can get consistent data from the script? The Powershell script takes about 1 minute to get all information per printer and we generally have 400 queues on average so it would need to wait for data to come.

My plan  ,if it is able to get consistent data, is to create an Excel file in PHP to put that data and give that file for user to download.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem exactly. Could you elaborate on the nature of the script, and what are those 400 queues you are talking about? Is the outcome of the script changing often?

Comment: The powershell scripts picks out data from Windows Printer class. So it takes about 1 minute to give the data out per printer. So for any given Server if goes into the server, takes all the data present in those classes and gives it out. But it takes time for this. So for 200 printers it will take approx 180-200 min and it would steadily be giving output as it goes printer by printer.

So what I want to know is how to get that data (more like stream of data) in a manner where I could assign various labels to data for easy transfer to Excel.

Comment: Once the data is retrieve, do you need to refresh it often? If not, just store everything in a database and then play with it as you see fit... If it is not too costly to refresh all possibilities, you could run a cron to keep your database up to date.

Comment: No the data doesn't need to be refreshed but it would come in stream minute by minute as the script keeps on executing. So Like this Printer1Information.....(after 1 minute)Printer2Information..... Like this until all the printers are exhausted. So how do I handle the input information in PHP. Like how do I transfer it from Powershell to PHP ? How do I enter it into the database FROM powershell exec command. That is my question.

Comment: To create your excel, you will need to wait for the end of the input anyways... If you just wanna see the live results on your PHP page, you are doing fine with this.